# Canvas.drawBitmap drawing the image with a yellow tint

Tags: android, bitmap, camera

I am trying to draw the 'Y' component as greyscale from the image I get from the Camera via onPreviewFrame.

I am using the version of Canvas.drawBitmap that takes an array of 'colors' as a parameter. The Android docs don't mention what format the Color is in, so I'm assuming ARGB 8888.

I do get an image showing up, but it is showing up with an odd Yellow tint.

Here is my code below:

```
  public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {    
    Canvas canvas = null;
    try {
      synchronized(mSurfaceHolder) {
        canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

        Size size = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();

        int width = size.width;
        int height = size.height;
        if (mHeight * mWidth != height * width)
        {
          mColors = new int[width * height];
          mHeight = height;
          mWidth = width;
          Log.i(TAG, "prewviw size = " + width + " x " + height);
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x ++) {
          for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            int yval = bytes[x + y * width];

            mColors[x + y * width] = (0xFF << 24) | (yval << 16) | (yval << 8) | yval;
          }
        }

        canvas.drawBitmap(mColors, 0, width, 0.f, 0.f, width, height, false, null);
      }
    }
    finally {
      if (canvas != null) {
        mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
      }
    }
  }
```

I've also tried using another version of Canvas.drawBitmap that takes a Bitmap as a parameter. I constructed the Bitmap in a similar way from the same array and I told it to use ARGB explicitly. But it still ended up being tinted Yellow!

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe your Camera is in Sepia mode?

Comment: The following line was wrong for negative values:

     int yval = bytes[x + y * width];

I was promoting a signed byte to an integer and then doing byte shifts on it. Adding a & 0xFF solves the problem.

Comment: This comment worked for me, but the picture comes out in graytones! It would be useful if you answered your own question, as it took me a while to spot the comment. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's a different approach, but the following works, and don't suffer for from the color problems of your solution:

```
    YuvImage yuv = new YuvImage(data, previewFormat, size.width, size.height, null);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    yuv.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, size.width, size.height), 50, out);

    byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, new Rect(0, 0, size.width, size.height), null);
```

Note: This probably needs to allocate data for every frame, which your solution doesn't.